# how to get details in <em> tags using preg_match_all

Tags: php

Im grabbing details using preg_match_all but i have a wired html tag placement to grab.. I need help to do this using preg_match_all!

this is the structure of html tag on that page !

```
<em>Details</em>I want to <em>get</em>
```

I abled to get just only "Details" using

```
  preg_match_all('/em>([^"]+)<\/em>/',$scrr,$match);
```

but i want to get whole thing like "Details i want to get"

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea. There are just too many variables that can cause things to go haywire.

Nonetheless:

```
<?php
    $scrr = "<em>Details</em>I want to <em>get</em>";

    preg_match_all('/<em>(.+?)<\/em>/is', $scrr, $match);

    print_r($match);
?>
```